# Trigger not updating checkbox properly

Tags: apex, trigger

My Opportunity object has an child object P_ODR__C. Opportunity obejct has checkbox field Nd_Check__c. I am updating it by trigger. 
I have a trigger on P_ODR__C updating checkbox on Opportunity record to true when when related record field TMMI__C start with 10. if 
Any related record had other than '10'  then uncheck.It is not updating checkbox properly. Anyone can please help.

Method in My Trigger trigger handler to update checkbox :

```
Boolean QueryrunOnce = false;
Public void updatecheck(List<P_ODR__C> triggerNew) 
{
    set<Id> OppIds = new set<id> ();
    set<Id> OppIdsFalse = new set <Id> ();
    List<Opportunity> ListOpp;
    If (Trigger.isInsert ||Trigger.isUpdate ) 
    {
        For (P_ODR__C od: triggerNew )
        { 
            If(!od.TMMI__C.startWith('10')) 
            {
                OppIdsFalse.add(od.Opportunity); 
            }else 
            {
                OppIds.add(od.Opportunity);
            }
        }
    }
    if(OppIds.size() > 0 && !QueryrunOnce ) 
    {
        ListOpp = New List<Opportunity> [Select Id,Nd_Check__c,(Select TMMI__C from Plan_sum__r where NOT TMMI__C Like '10' ) from Opportunity where id:=OppIds];
    }
    If(ListOpp.size()> 0 && !ListOpp.isEmpty()) 
    {
        For (Opportunity Opps: ListOpp ) 
        {
            If (OppIdsFalse.contains(Opps.id) ||Opps.Plan_sum__r.size() > 0 ) 
            {
                Opps.Nd_Check__c = false;
            }
            Else 
            {
                Opps.Nd_Check__c = true; 
            }
        }
        update ListOpp;
    }
}
```

Developer Org Code :

```
trigger UpdateOppForReleaseRec on Release__c (before update,before delete,after insert,after update,after delete) 
{   
    try 
    {
        Map<Id, Opportunity> oppMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();
        for(Release__c record: trigger.New) 
        {
            if (record.Plan_Sum__r.sub_segment__c!='MM') {
                system.debug('This record is Added for update '+ record.Plan_Sum__r.sub_segment__c );
                oppMap.put(record.Opportunity__c, new Opportunity(Id=record.Opportunity__c, set_rel__c=true));
            }
            //oppMap.put(record.Opportunity__c, new Opportunity(Id=record.Opportunity__c, set_rel__c=true));
            system.debug('Testing  >> '+ record);
        }
        for(AggregateResult result : [SELECT Opportunity__c Id 
                                      FROM Release__c 
                                      WHERE Opportunity__c = :oppMap.keySet() 
                                      AND (NOT Test__c LIKE '14%') 
                                      //AND Plan_Sum__r.sub_segment__c!='MM'
                                      GROUP BY Opportunity__c]) 
        {
            system.debug('Testing-In >>'+ result);
            oppMap.get((Id)result.get('Id')).set_rel__c = false;   
        }
        update oppMap.values();
    }
    catch(exception e) 
    {
        System.debug('The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());

    }
}
```

Comment: This code shouldn't compile. Please verify your code.

Comment: @sdfcfox Yes because I had to change names so it has some error do you see any logical issue in it ? It would be great if you can give some clue !! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your *main* problem is that the checkbox will sometimes not be unchecked because any opportunities in OppIdFalse will not be in ListOpp, because they were never queried. The easiest way to resolve this is a complete restructuring of your code.

As a related error, if you want "starts with", you need to use a wildcard, as in `LIKE '10%'`. That was probably part of your problem as well. Also, the entire code was a lot more verbose than it needed to be.

First, we build a map of opportunities we want to update, then we query for those records that meet our criteria, finish up checking the appropriate boxes, and perform an update. Here's what that would look like:

```
Map<Id, Opportunity> opps = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();
for(P_ODR__c record: triggerNew) {
  opps.put(record.Opportunity__c, new Opportunity(Id=record.Opportunity__c, Nd_Check__c=true));
}
for(AggregateResult result: [SELECT Opportunity__c Id FROM P_ODR__c 
     WHERE Opportunity__c = :opps.keySet() AND NOT TMMI__c LIKE '10%' GROUP BY Opportunity__c]) {
  opps.get((Id)result.get('Id')).Nd_Check__c = false;
}
update opps.values();
```

Comment: @Sdfcfox.. Simple and Awesome approach.  Thanks you much!!  I changed my logic as you suggested and it worked perfectly and better performance. One question anything needed to stop recursive because existing method has boolean QueryrunOnce.

Comment: @ArvindSingh Unless you have an opportunity trigger updating those records, there's not much else you need to do.

Comment: I just checked and i can see opportunity trigger also update those record based on some other condition. do i need to use any static variable ?

Comment: @ArvindSingh If you're experiencing an infinite loop, then maybe, otherwise don't worry about it. All things being equal, a better solution than a static variable is to query the opportunities involved and see if they need to be updated based on their current status (e.g. if the opportunity is already unchecked, and the new value is unchecked, do not perform an update).

Comment: I have a question if you can help me. Logic suggested by you is working fine for me but i need to add one more condition for Sub_segment__c to query so my loop will be like   for(AggregateResult result: [SELECT Opportunity__c Id FROM P_ODR__c 
     WHERE Opportunity__c = :opps.keySet() AND Opportunity__r.Sub_Segment__c != 'MM' AND (NOT TMMI__c LIKE '10%') GROUP BY Opportunity__c]) {
  opps.get((Id)result.get('Id')).Nd_Check__c = false;
}  If i do like this will it work fine and what about performance ? Please advise.

Comment: @ArvindSingh Performance should be acceptable, and it should work, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks. After updating the code it did not work. I added one debug for Opportunity__r.Sub_Segment__c and it is coming Null every time. I tried Similar logic in my Developer Org but there also it is not working and giving error. Please see Updated Developer Code above. Any suggestion

Comment: I want to Skip all opportunity which has segment=MM I am not sure why value is coming as Null.

Comment: @ArvindSingh Related records [are not populated by default](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/119671/2984). You need to query those records first.

Comment: I am trying to get parent record field record.Plan_Sum__r.sub_segment__c!='MM'. Sub_Segment is picklist on Opportunity and I have given child relationship name as plan_sum_r. I am trying to get value from parent record.  Do you mean i need to get opportunity 
 sub_segment__c from using another SOQL  ?

Comment: @ArvindSingh yes, that's correct. Use the pattern shown in the other answer for performance reasons.