# CPQ execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.FinalException: Record is read-only

Tags: before-trigger, after-trigger, cpq

On CPQ quote object When we click on submit for approval button, status is changed to In review, when the status is changed to in review. I Have to populate a field from quote associated quotelineitems product.

When I tired to do by using After update I m not getting the status value as In Review in debug logs

I am getting this error System.FinalException: Record is read-only

How Do i capture the status as inreview after approval process and update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a "before update" trigger instead. As the error implies, you cannot change the status (or any other value) of a record in an after trigger, as the data is already committed to the database. You will still be able to see the new values in a "before update" trigger, but those changes can be altered before being committed.

Comment: When I use before update status value is still Draft, not In Review. So, my logic is not firing

Comment: You'll need to read your debug logs and/or write some unit tests to discover why. It's not immediately obvious in your code where the mistake is. Or, alternatively, you may have another trigger or process that's changing the status afterwards. This is one of those times where you'll likely need to learn about debugging to figure out a solution.

Comment: Thanks i figured out there was workflow rule causing  issue. Before update is working

Comment: In the Last block of code I am checking condition for quote type and quote contract end date. Although the contract has end date it gives null and not entering the loop. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: @teeshu I'm not sure I follow. Usually it's because you're looking at the wrong record. [Relationship fields are not automatically populated.](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/119671). Make sure you're querying the data you need and using a map.

Comment: Thank you, it worked