# Is it possible to access the Lead ID on a newly created Campaign Member through the Trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

I'm writing a trigger on Campaign members, and I'd like to use the ID of the Lead associated with the campaign member. When I try to access the Lead Id in the trigger it returns null.

Is it possible to access this ID?

```
trigger FirstCampaign on CampaignMember (after insert) {
    for(CampaignMember cm : Trigger.New) {
        system.debug('The lead ID IS: ' + cm.Lead.ID);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Relationships are not automatically populated, such that `Trigger.new[0].Lead.Id` will always be null. This is always true for all parent and child relationships. See answers like [this one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/119671/2984) that explain what you'd do. This is a slightly different scenario, though. You simply need to use the correct field. `Lead.Id` is a reference to a sObject's field, while `LeadId` is the Lead's Id as it exists on the `CampaignMember`. Generally speaking, you will always want to use the lookup field's Id instead of the relationship's Id for performance reasons anyways.

```
trigger FirstCampaign on CampaignMember (after insert) {
    for(CampaignMember cm : Trigger.New) {
        system.debug('The lead ID IS: ' + cm.LeadId);
    }   
}
```