# Triggers on Contact object

Tags: trigger

If we are creating or updating Contact with account then we need to fill custom field on it Account_LastName(I've created this field on my org) this field should be filled with related Account Name + his Id. In case if we are changing account name this should also be reflected in that field
Here is what i did for now:
Trigger:

```
trigger ContTrigRoma on Contact(before insert, before update){
    
    if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert){
        TriggerHandler.handlerForRoma(Trigger.new);
    } else if (Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isUpdate) {
        
    }
}
```

Handler:

```
public with sharing class TriggerHandler {
    public static void handlerForRoma(List<Contact> contacts){
        for (Contact cont : contacts) {
            if(cont.AccountId != null){
                cont.Account_LastName__c = cont.AccountId + cont.Account.Name;
            }
        }
        insert contacts;
    }
}
```

For some reason i can't even test it by creating contact object because i get an error :
DML statement cannot operate on trigger.new or trigger.old

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to perform DML when modifying Trigger.new; any changes you make will automatically be committed to the database. Remove the `insert contacts;` statement.

You can't reference parent or child objects directly from Trigger.new. You need to query for those records, as demonstrated in [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/119623/2984), and as mentioned in my blog post, [The Aggregate Query Update Pattern](https://sfdcfox.blogspot.com/2017/03/the-aggregate-query-update-pattern.html).

Your final code should look like:

```
public static void handlerForRoma(List<Contact> contacts){
    Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>();
    for(Contact record: contacts) {
        accounts.put(record.AccountId, null);
    }
    accounts.putAll([SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Id = :accounts.keySet()]);
    for(Contact record: contacts) {
        Account parent = accounts.get(record.AccountId);
        if(parent != null) {
            record.Account_LastName__c = record.AccountId + parent.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To clarify for others: This only works when you're in a `before` trigger, and you _must_ modify the instances of the records in `trigger.new`. If you write a query like `List<Contact> conList = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new];` and then modify the record instances in `conList`, the automatic update behavior of `before` triggers won't happen.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding 1 point to sfdcfox comment-
you can simply achieve this by created formula field on the contact that will reference the account.name.
You can/should use it in case the Account_LastName should not be changed manually on the contact level to other value then the accont name.